# jsPDF fromHTML(): Text Align Center not Working

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

I'm trying to generate html code to a pdf document using jsPDF. Everything works as expected, except the text alignment.

Generated PDF:
[image: Generated PDF Document]

Javascript:

```
var html = '<p style="text-align:center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>';

pdf.fromHTML(html, 20, 90, {
    'width': 180
});

pdf.save('test.pdf');
```

Why is the text not centered correctly?

**UPDATE: Resolved my issue ditching jsPDF and using [PDFmake](http://pdfmake.org) instead.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved my issue ditching jsPDF and using [**PDFmake**](http://pdfmake.org) instead.

**UPDATE: Here's an example code:**

```
var document = {
    content: 
    [
        { 
            text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
            alignment: 'center' //it's that simple :)
        }
    ]
}

// save the PDF
pdfMake.createPdf(document).download("demo.pdf");
```

Comment: Add snippet or explanation to accomplish the same using PDFmake. In order to qualify this as an answer.

It will helpful for others also.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Purushoth in the link there is a demo page where you can see this example. Either way, i'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Sure please update it. Personally I have check PDFmake docs and examples but for this question context it would be good to have a detailed answer here.

Thanks!